# Showing $\frac{x}{1+x}<\log(1+x)<x$ for all $x>0$ using the mean value theorem

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, inequality, logarithms

I want to show that $$\frac{x}{1+x}<\log(1+x)<x$$ for all $x>0$ using the mean value theorem. I tried to prove the two inequalities separately.

$$\frac{x}{1+x}<\log(1+x) \Leftrightarrow \frac{x}{1+x} -\log(1+x) <0$$

Let $$f(x) = \frac{x}{1+x} -\log(1+x).$$ Since $$f(0)=0$$ and $$f'(x)= \frac{1}{(1+x)^2}-\frac{1}{1+x}<0$$ for all $x > 0$,  $f(x)<0$ for all $x>0$.  Is this correct so far?

I go on with the second part:
Let $f(x) = \log(x+1)$. Choose $a=0$ and $x>0$ so that there is, according to the mean value theorem, an $x_0$ between $a$ and $x$ with

$f'(x_0)=\frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a} \Leftrightarrow \frac{1}{x_0+1}=\frac{ \log(x+1)}{x}$.

Since $$x_0>0 \Rightarrow  \frac{1}{x_0+1}<1.$$ $$\Rightarrow 1 > \frac{1}{x_0+1}= \frac{ \log(x+1)}{x} \Rightarrow x> \log(x+1)$$

Comment: How did you arrive at that first equivalence, $\frac{x}{1+x}<\log(1+x) \Longleftrightarrow -\log(1+x)\frac{x}{1+x}<0$?  Also, you've calculated $f'(x)$ incorrectly.

Comment: By subtracting it. Wolfram Alpha says, my derivation is correct...

Comment: **Hint**: If you subtract, there should be a plus sign to indicate addition. The way you have it now looks like they're being multiplied.

Comment: I've just copied it wrong, but used it correct in my derivation..

Comment: I know; it was tongue in cheek.

Answer (score 5):

By Definition of log, for any $x>0$ We have
$$\frac{x}{x+1} =\int_{0}^x\frac{dt}{x+1} \le \int_{0}^x\frac{dt}{t+1} =\color{red}{\ln(x+1 )}=\int_{0}^x\frac{dt}{t+1}  \le \int_{0}^x\frac{dt}{1}  = x $$

Thus,

$$\frac{x}{x+1} \le \ln(x+1 ) \le   x $$

Answer (score 2):

As a consequence of MVT, there is a $\xi\in(0,x)$, such that
$$
\log(1+x)=\log(1+x)-\log 1=x\cdot \left(\log(1+x)\right)'_{x=\xi}=x\cdot\frac{1}{1+\xi}<x.
$$
Let $y=\frac{x}{1+x}$. Then there is $\xi\in\big(0,y\big)$, such that
\begin{align}
\log(1+x)&=-\log\left(\frac{1}{1+x}\right)=\log 1-\log\left(1-\frac{x}{1+x}\right) \\&=
\log 1-\log\left(1-y\right) =
y\left(\log(1-y)\right)'_{y=\xi}=y\cdot\frac{1}{1-\xi}>y=\frac{x}{x+1.}
\end{align}

Answer (score 2):

Substitute $x=y-1$ to get $$1-y^{-1}<\log y<y-1$$ for all $y>1$. Now note  $$\int_1^y t^{-2}dt <\int_1^y t^{-1}dt <\int_1^y dt $$ for $y>1$.

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to ask if there are other ways to solve this and wrote my solution on the way, this question didn't turn up at first when I was searching.

Well here's another way to solve this that doesn't use MVT:

Define $g(x)=\ln(1+x)-x, \ g'(x)=\frac1 {1+x} -1$

$g'(x)=0\implies x=0$ and after checking it is a maximum. so it holds that $g(x)<g(0)$.

Define: $h(x)=\frac x {1+x}-\ln(1+x),\ h'(x)=-\frac x {(1+x)^2}$

$h'(x)=0 \implies x=0$ and it's also a maximum so $h(x)<h(0)$.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're not asking for a solution (which is great!) but just confirmation that what you have so far is correct.  Yes (after some edits), so far so good, except how do you justify that $f(0) = 0$ and $f'(x) < 0$ for $x > 0$ implies that $f(x) < 0$ for $x > 0$?  What's the key part of your question that you haven't used yet?

Comment: Using that if $f'(x)<0~ \Rightarrow ~f(x)$ is strictly monotonically decreasing?

Comment: That fact is usually seen as an easy consequence of MVT.  To what extent are you expected to "use" MVT in your solution?  You're probably fine to use consequences like these without remark.  I just ask because of the explicit "using the mean value theorem" in your question statement.

Comment: $f(0)=\frac{0}{1}-log(1)=0-0=0$