# Prove by Mean Value Theorem $\frac{x}{1+x}<\ln(1+x)<x$ for $x>0$

Tags: calculus, inequality, logarithms

Prove for $x>0$
$$
\frac{x}{1+x}<\ln(1+x)<x
$$
I tried writing $\ln(1+x)=\ln(1+x)-\ln(1)$ and using the MVT for the $(1,1+x)$ interval. I eventually could prove the inequality but how do I have to prove even for $(0,1)$

Comment: can it be done without Taylor?

Comment: I know but we haven't quite studied Taylor series so if you could help with some hint, I just don't know how to prove for (0;1) interval because the rest I have done

Comment: I will think on it; I don't currently have it solved either :)

Comment: See also: [Showing $\frac{x}{1+x}<\log(1+x)<x$ for all $x>0$ using the mean value theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/652581)

Answer (score 3):

By the mean value theorem, given $x > 0$, there exists $c \in (0,x)$ such that $f(x) - f(0) = f'(c)x$, i.e., $\ln(1 + x) = \frac{x}{1 + c}$. Since $0 < c < x$, $\frac{1}{1 + x} < \frac{1}{1 + c} < 1$. Therefore $\frac{x}{1 + x} < \frac{x}{1 + c} < x$, i.e.,

$$\frac{x}{1 + x} < \ln(1 + x) < x.$$