# Show $p< -\log(1-p)$ for $0<p<1$

Tags: real-analysis, inequality

Show $$p< -\log(1-p)$$ for $0<p<1$. I thought about using Taylor expansion, is that the way to go?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [prove $\log(1+x)<x$ for $>0$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1396776/prove-log1xx-for-x0)

Comment: Or better this one: [Show that $\ln (x) \leq x-1 $](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1222872/show-that-ln-x-leq-x-1)

Comment: Also closely related (and in fact equivalent): [Simplest or nicest proof that $1+x \le e^x$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/504663/42969)

Answer (score 1):

You want to prove $f(p):=-p-\ln(1-p)$ is positive on $(0,\,1)$. This follows from $f(0)=0$ and $f^\prime(p)=\frac{p}{1-p}>0$. The Taylor series $f(p)=\sum_{n\ge2}\frac{p^n}{n}$ also works, as you suggested.

Answer (score 0):

You have for $0<p<1$

$$-\log(1-p) = \int_{1-p}^1\frac{dt}{t}> \int_{1-p}^11\;dt = 1-(1-p) = p$$