# mean value theorem inequality homework

Tags: calculus, derivatives, inequality

[image]

So I think the interval for this question is (n,n+1) and the function is y=lnx, based what the inequality looks like, but I don't know how to approach this question the "proper" way. Also I am not sure what the (n+1)/n does. so if someone can explain it I would be very happy.

Thanks

Comment: $\ln{\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)}<\frac{1}{n}$. What does this remind you of when you simplify?

Comment: @Element118 , I don't really know... sorry. But thanks for the input.

Comment: Can you show that $\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)^n$ is increasing?

Comment: @Element118 it would be increasing... but how would it relate though?

Comment: Do you know that the limit is $e$? What can you conclude by taking the $\log$ of this expression?

Comment: @Element118 ooohhh I see. thank you very much =D

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/652581/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1887583/321264

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Intuition behind logarithm inequality: $1 - \frac1x \leq \log x \leq x-1$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/324345/intuition-behind-logarithm-inequality-1-frac1x-leq-log-x-leq-x-1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**  $\ln' x=1/x$ and its value is between $1/(n+1)$ and $1/n$.

Comment: Yes. so the slope of the secant line connecting the 2 points is between the tangent at the 2 ends. but where does n+1/n come in?

Comment: $ln(n+1)-ln(n)=ln(\frac{n+1}{n})$