# Solving limit $\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (\frac{1}{n+1}+ ... +\frac{1}{2n})$

Tags: limits, harmonic-numbers

Could anyone help me solving the following limit?

$\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty} (\frac{1}{n+1}+ ... +\frac{1}{2n})$

I think it should just be 0 since we can distribute the limite inside the sum, but I am not sure of this answer. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: You *can't* "distribute the limit inside the sum", because the number of terms depends on $n$. If the limit exists, it has to be between $\frac12$ and $1$.

Comment: Hint: $\sum_{k=1}^n \frac{1}{n+k} = \frac1n \sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{1+\frac{k}{n}}$, does the RHS look familiar?

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1351714/find-the-limit-lim-n-to-infty-sum-k-1n-frac1kn/1351729#1351729

Comment: Apply squeeze theorem on the inequality given in this question: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/1895591/72031

Comment: See also: [The limit of truncated sums of harmonic series, $\lim\limits_{k\to\infty}\sum_{n=k+1}^{2k}{\frac{1}{n}}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/73550)

Answer (score 4):

We can approximate the sum by definite integrals from below and above in the following way (see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation#Approximation_by_definite_integrals) for more details)
$$
\log\biggl(2-\frac1{n+1}\biggr)=\int_{n+1}^{2n+1}x^{-1}\mathrm dx\le\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\frac1k\le\int_n^{2n}x^{-1}\mathrm dx=\log 2.
$$
Since both of the bounds converge to the same limit as $n\to\infty$, we have that the limit as $n\to\infty$ is $\log 2$.

Answer (score 0):

Notice $\sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{1}{n+i} = \sum_{i = 1}^{2n} \frac{1}{i} -\sum_{i = 1}^n \frac{1}{i} = H_{2n} - H_{n} $

Where $H_n$ stands for the $n^{th}$ term of harmoic numbers.

Therefore the limit equals $\lim_{n \to \infty }  H_{2n} - H_{n}$

By the [asymptotic expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#Calculation) of $H_{n} ~ \ln(n) + \gamma + O(\frac{1}{n})$ when n goes up to infinity.

$$\lim_{n \to \infty }  H_{2n} - H_{n}  = \ln(2n) - \ln(n) = ln(2)$$