# Squeeze theorem inequality: $\frac{n}{1+n} < \ln(1+\frac{1}{n})^n < 1$

Tags: inequality, logarithms

show that for $n>1$, $$\frac{n}{1+n} <  \ln(1+\frac{1}{n})^n  < 1$$

by using $\frac{1}{n} < \ln n $
and $\ln(1+n) < n$ for $n>1$

I am unable to prove $\frac{n}{1+n} <  \ln(1+\frac{1}{n})^n $

Comment: $1+1/n=(n+1)/n$ take log base n both sides

Comment: Similar: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1887583/show-that-for-all-n-1-frac1n-1-log1-frac1n-frac1n/

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{1}{\frac{n+1}{n}}=\frac{n}{n+1}<\ln(\frac{n+1}{n})=\ln(1+\frac{1}{n})<\frac{1}n$$

For $n>1$, we have $0<\ln(1+\frac{1}{n})<1, $ so
$$\ln(1+\frac{1}{n})^n<1$$
Also, $$1>\ln(1+\frac{1}{n})^n=n*\ln(1+\frac{1}{n})>n(\frac{n}{n+1})>\frac{n}{n+1}\text{ , for }n>1$$
finishes the proof

Comment: From $\ln(1 + \frac{1}{n}) < 1$, $\left(\ln(1 + \frac{1}{n})\right)^n < 1$, but $\left(\ln(1 + \frac{1}{n})\right)^n \neq n \cdot \ln(1 + \frac{1}{n}) = \ln\left((1 + \frac{1}{n})^n\right)$

Answer (score 0):

One may observe that
$$
f(x)=\ln(1+x)-\frac{x}{1+x},\qquad x \in[0,1],
$$ is such that
$$
f(0)=0,\quad f'(x)=\frac{x}{(1+x)^2}\ge0,\qquad x \in[0,1],
$$ giving
$$
\ln(1+x)-\frac{x}{1+x}\ge0,\qquad x \in[0,1].
$$ By putting $x:=\dfrac1n$, $n \ge1$, one gets
$$
n\ln\left(1+\frac1n\right)-\frac{n}{1+n}\ge 0
$$ as wanted.