# Using the Mean Value Theorem to prove an inequality

Tags: calculus, inequality

Can someone help me to solve this question:

Using the Mean Value Theorem, show that for all positive integers n:

$$ n\ln{\big(1+\frac{1}{n}}\big)\le 1.$$

I've tried basically every function out there, and I can't get it. I know how to prove it using another technique, but how do you do it using MVT?

Thank you very  much in advance,

C.G

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1887583/321264, https://math.stackexchange.com/q/652581/321264,

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Let $f(x)=\ln(1+x)$, then $f^{\prime}(x)=\frac{1}{1+x}$, hence by the mean value theorem for any $x>0$ there is some $0<t<x$ such that
$$ \frac{f(x)-f(0)}{x-0}=f^{\prime}(t)=\frac{1}{1+t} $$
Since $f(0)=0$ and $\frac{1}{1+t}<1$, this implies that
$$\frac{f(x)}{x}<1$$
for all $x>0$, hence
$$ \ln(1+x)=f(x)<x$$
for all $x>0$. Now taking $x=\frac{1}{n}$ we get
$$ \ln\Big(1+\frac{1}{n}\Big)<\frac{1}{n} $$
for all $n\geq 1$, which is the desired result.

Comment: thanks so much! My mistake was that I was taking 1 as my lower bound instead of 0...

Answer (score 6):

Let $f(x)=\ln x$ on interval $[n,n+1]$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. $f$ is an increasing function with $f'(x)=\dfrac{1}{n}$, using the Mean Value Theorem,
$$f(n+1)-f(n)=f'(c)(n+1-n)=\frac1c$$
for a $c\in[n,n+1]$.

Hence,
$$n<c<n+1$$
$$\frac{1}{n+1}<\frac1c<\frac1n$$
$$\frac{1}{n+1}<f(n+1)-f(n)<\frac1n$$
$$\frac{1}{n+1}<\ln\frac{n+1}{n}<\frac1n$$
with right inequality
$$ n\ln{\big(1+\frac{1}{n}}\big)< 1,$$
for all positive integers $n$.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**: Write this as 
$$\frac{\ln(1+\frac1n)-\ln(1)}{\frac 1n}.$$