# Proving an inequality involving the logarithm function: $\frac{1}{n+1} \leq \ln \left(1+\frac 1n\right) \leq \frac 1n$

Tags: inequality, logarithms

The question is to prove the inequality $$\frac{1}{n+1} \leq \ln \left(1+\frac 1n\right) \leq \frac 1n\\\forall n \geq 1, n\in \mathbb N$$

I tried using Taylor expansion but couldn't figure out anything. Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe you can try mathematical induction if you know about it. Or calculus.

Comment: Related: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/324345/intuition-behind-logarithm-inequality-1-frac1x-leq-log-x-leq-x-1

Comment: See also: [Show that, for all $n > 1: \frac{1}{n + 1} < \log(1 + \frac1n) < \frac1n.$](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1887583) (Found [using Approach0](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=%24%5Cfrac%7B1%7D%7Bn%2B1%7D%20%5Cleq%20%5Cln%20%5Cleft(1%2B%5Cfrac%201n%5Cright)%20%5Cleq%20%5Cfrac%201n%24&p=1).)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Suppose $n<x<n+1$. Then
$$ \frac{1}{n+1}<\frac{1}{x}<\frac{1}{n}. $$
Integrate this with respect to $x$, from $n$ to $n+1$. Then
$$ \frac{1}{n+1}<\log{(n+1)}-\log{n}<\frac{1}{n}, $$
and the middle is $\log{(1+\frac{1}{n})}$.

Comment: I love how the integration doesn't affect the bounds here. Quite interesting! +1 for sure!

Answer (score 11):

Given an integer $n>0$, Mean Value Theorem implies that there exist a real number $\xi\in\left(1,1+\frac1n\right)$ s.t.
$$\frac{\ln\left(1+\frac1n\right)-\ln1}{\left(1+\frac1n\right)-1}=\frac1{\xi}\qquad\text{i.e.}\qquad \frac n{n+1}<n\ln\left(1+\tfrac1n\right)<1$$
So
$$\frac1{n+1}<\ln\left(1+\tfrac1n\right)<\frac1n$$

Comment: (+1) also nice!

Comment: I always feel like using the Mean Value Theorem is nuking the fly until I remember that it's actually one of the more fundamental theorems in Calculus.