# Prove $\frac{1}{n+1}\le \log\left(1+\frac{1}{n}\right)\le \frac{1}{n} ,\forall n\ge1$ if $\log x= \int_{1}^{x}\frac{dt}{t},x>0$

Tags: calculus, integration

I know it is very simple but something is going amiss.

We can see here that $\log(1+\dfrac{1}{n})=\displaystyle \int_{n}^{n+1}\dfrac{dt}{t}$

if $t \in[n,n+1]$, $\dfrac{1}{n+1}\le\dfrac{1}{t}\le\dfrac{1}{n}$

I want to show that $\dfrac{1}{n+1}\le\displaystyle \int_{n}^{n+1}\dfrac{dt}{t}\le\dfrac{1}{n}$.

Can I straight infer that? If so what is the logic behind it? I was thinking of using $\displaystyle \Sigma_{i=1}^{n}$ and sandwiching $\displaystyle \int_{n}^{n+1}\dfrac{dt}{t}$ between. But confused !

Comment: $\frac{1}{n+1} \le \frac 1t \le \frac 1n$ for all $t$ in the interval ...

Comment: Exactly if $t \in [n,n+1]$, I thought it too that way only. Am I right ?

Comment: If you have to ask what is the logic behind it, you cannot straight infer it.

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen See I changed my edits there, I assumed it without putting it there. It seemed to me quite obvious. That's why I asked. And I said "Can I infer it?"

Comment: Asked before [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/324345/321264). Look out for linked posts.

Comment: like this one:https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1887583/show-that-for-all-n-1-frac1n-1-log1-frac1n-frac1n.

Comment: I have changed the formatting of the title so as to
[make it take up less vertical space](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9686/290189) --
this is a policy to ensure that the scarce space on the main page is distributed evenly over the questions.
See [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9730) for more information. Please take this into consideration for future
questions. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$n\le t\le n+1$$

$$\frac {1}{n+1} \le \frac {1}{t}\le \frac {1}{n}$$

$$ \int _n ^{n+1}\frac {dt}{n+1} \le \int _n ^{n+1}\frac {dt}{t}\le \int _n ^{n+1}\frac {dt}{n}$$
$$\dfrac{1}{n+1}\le\displaystyle \int_{n}^{n+1}\dfrac{dt}{t}\le\dfrac{1}{n}$$

Answer (score 2):

Yes, because $\frac{1}{n+1} \leq \frac{1}{t} \leq \frac{1}{n}$ for $t \in [n, n+1]$, so
$$\int_{n}^{n+1} \frac{1}{n+1} \, dt \leq \int_{n}^{n+1} \frac{1}{t} \, dt \leq \int_{n}^{n+1} \frac{1}{n} \, dt$$
then your inequality follows.